# Which management API implements Auth0 Groups feature

Tags: java, authorization, single-sign-on, auth0

Which management API implements Auth0 Groups feature
https://auth0.com/docs/api/authorization-extension#groups

We are **not** able to identify the interface which implements Groups in https://github.com/auth0/auth0-java

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/auth0/auth0-authorization-extension:

> The Authorization Extension is in maintenance mode. We do not plan on adding new features to the extension as we are working to bring features of the extension into the core Auth0 platform. Bug fixes and security patches will still be made.

Also see https://github.com/auth0/auth0-authorization-extension/issues/199. It doesn't look like they will build SDKs for it.